# changing job after 1 month of promotion

Tags: promotion

I have been working in X department for the past 3 years and have been promoted to Manager in Y department last month, through an internal job posting.

However, I have just received a very interesting offer from outside.

Please guide me: is it good to leave the present organization and move to another, will it be ethical as I'm not able to decide and I feel of betraying the trust of the company if accept the offer from outside.

I had applied through internal vacancy

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate in your question a bit more on what bases the promotion went. Was there an internal vacancy you applied for? Or did the organisation ask you if you wanted another position? This kind of context can be relevant in making this decision.

Comment: Resigning after a promotion doesn't look good. Is it worth it though? We can't tell you. That's something only you can decide for yourself.

Comment: Probably close enough - [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149)

Comment: Once you explain your current situation to the outside company, how do you plan on explaining why you are looking for another job?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? He does not want to resign from a new job. Worked there for over three years ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a question where you can be guided in. This is a question where people can give their opinion on. You can use this opinions to form your own, but **you** are the one who has to make the decision and do what **you** think is best.

That said, I think it is not right to leave this quick after a promotion. Not knowing the whole story, but you're stating that you applied through an internal vacancy, so you are the one who said, I want this position. Therefore it is, in my opinion, your responsibility to hold your part of the deal. But still, it is your decision, and if you are 100% sure that you need to leave, and your contract allows you to do so, you surely can leave...

Comment: Please note that "there" is a place, not "belonging to them."

Comment: My bad, stupid typo