# Should change my job after only 2 month?

Tags: new-job, job-change

I was working for a marketing company before as a software consultant for their clients after 1 year and 3 month, I decided to get a new job with a better offer which is where I am working now as a Software Consultant. A long time ago one of my friends who is the manager of the software development department of a bank told me that he wants to work with me but It was difficult to get in. After one year I have received his called and told me that now there is an opportunity of working as a software analyst and I would be working with a very important project.

They are offering the same salary I am getting with my current job. But the benefits at the end of the year are higher. where I am working now It is a small business with 4 employees. Working on a bank would be great for me because there are more opportunities to get new positions and a wage increase every year and I'll be working on a very important project there I am a Systems Engineer and only 21 years old.

If I were in my previous job I would have told him yes without thinking twice but I am very new on my current job and I would feel bad If I leave now.

I would like to hear your advice and thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: I had to flag because this question comes up almost every week on this website and is all over the internet. A simple Google search answers this.

Comment: We cannot tell you whether you should take this job or that job. What you should do is purely for you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

See the other answers, but yes, you can leave.  It's business, your current employer will recover.  They may not be happy, and you probably won't be able to work there again.  As for other future potentials, just sell them on how you had been waiting for the bank job to come up and it was unfortunate that it came up when it did, but it was a once in a career opportunity you just couldn't pass on.

Answer (score 0):

By all means if you think you will enjoy the work, be better remunerated etc... That said however, you don't want your CV to show a string of short stints in different companies as it could suggest you lack commitment or get bored quickly (or worse!).

I'm of the opinion that you can adequately explain away a single gap in your CV or a very short spell with an employer. It gets trickier if you have more than one.

I think if you *do* change jobs you need to be prepared to commit to it and stick out at least two years (probably a bit more because you are still young so presumably don't have a 4 or 5 year spell at one place).