# I am disappointed with my new job its appropriate to resign?

Tags: resignation

I am a newly hired staff member who's been with the company for less than a month and it seems that I am not comfortable working with my managers and a new colleague. I feel that the expectation of my manager is too high for what I can provide. When I started my job, my manager gave me all the job orientations in one go and I also didn't have a proper mentor. I told her I'm a slow learner, though I feel embarrassed every time she speaks to me because it seems that she treated me like a daft. I'm thinking it's a challenge, but I'm uneasy when I'm at work and I'm not happy at all. Is it ok to leave my job and resign?

Comment: Why don't you just look for a new job and if someone hires you, you're all set.

Comment: Yes after 1 month is too soon unless you have something else lined up that is clearly better. You do not want to set a pattern for yourself of being a person who cannot work unless everything is perfect. Persistence is the most critical success factor of all. Giving up so soon is a poor indicator of your ability to succeed anywhere. Most jobs have no mentor, you should never expect to have one. You need to learn to pick things up on your own.

Comment: Honestly I have a job interview tomorrow.I don't know what can I do if I got that job..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: @jamesmorris: in case if you want to quit and looking for a new job, just don't put this 1 month job on your CV.

Answer (score 4):

After only one month at many jobs, it's completely normal to feel overwhelmed, not happy, a bit stupid.  You're starting to see how things work, but don't know nearly enough to do any of it well.  You are starting to see what the expectations are, but have no way to do well enough to do them at that level.  **This is normal.**

Sure, you can give up.  You can look for a different, and easier job.  But the better way is to keep trying, keep learning, keep asking questions.  After six months you should be feeling a bit more confident, and are starting to sometimes do as well as expected.  But even then you may do not as well as others.  By the time you've been there a year, you should be up to speed.  And then you'll have more confidence in yourself, because you know you can do a hard thing.

By then, you'll also have a much better idea of the job itself, and whether there are underlying issues that make you still not like the job.  Since a job search can often take a few months, if you start looking at a year and half or so, then this job won't be a short job that looks bad on your resume.  If you quit after 1 month, it will make it MUCH harder to find the next job.