# Things to do when leaving a job early for another job

Tags: job-change, resignation

I was fresh out of school and been applying to multiple places as a software engineer. In the end, I was being interviewed 2 companies. One (noted as A) quickly processed stuff and got back to me with an offer in a couple of days. The other company (noted as B), told me that they are still considering the candidates.

Company A wasn't my 1st option and definitely was not my favorite company, but since I had to pay bills and stuff, I decided to take the offer from company A. Its been about 2 weeks since I started working at company A. However, I got an email from company B, and they offered me a job. I like company B over company A in multiple areas (salary, things I'll be working on, benefits etc), but I'm not sure on how to inform my company that I will be leaving and what steps I need to take.

I have nothing against company A. The people I work with are nice and the company is also a nice place. I'm not leaving company A because my boss was rude to me, or I am getting underpaid then I should be. I just want to leave company A because I like what company B does more.

This could be a duplicate of another post I found answered by [bethlakshmi](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully) . But my situation is a bit different from the post, and I was more interested in what are some of the things that I should do and how I should inform my company and leave in good terms (of course, I won't be able to leave the company in 100% good terms, since I am leaving them only after a few weeks since I've started working. But I want to be able to minimize the amount of negative images of myself). And I don't feel comfortable informing them that I am leaving the company in order to work at another place.

Any tips or experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I guess a lot of answers were a bit off. I was asking what I should do at my current company and how I should approach it (ex telling your supervisor / HR person that you are quiting, but not sure how to disclose this information to them, saying good byes to your team member, finishing w/e I was working on etc)

Comment: Do you have any reason in mind that why you want to leave company A? Because if HR of company A ask you reason for leaving , you should have ready with professional and satisfied answer. To tell them like because you like company B then it could put negative impact.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd just keep the cards close to your chest.

Submit your two weeks notice, if asked why in an exit interview, you received a more lucrative offer. Period.

No need to get into the nitty gritty details.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would come out clean.
I would say the truth, politely stated of course.

Tell them that you like i.e. the working environment and colleagues. However, there was a proposition made to you which you cannot deny nor you want to. **It would be also better if you avoided talking about company B to A.**

Keep things professional and formal. It's not so uncommon for someone who is new in a job to leave. You haven't settled down yet. It's how job hunting and business work.

Comment: Also, consider seeing how long you could delay starting at Company B, so you can give Company A a longer-than-usual period of notice before your departure.

Comment: @Careerasaurus.com - probably not necessary after 2 weeks working there as a first job: OP is almost certainly not working on anything critical enough to require an extended handoff.

Comment: That was what I also thought, but then again I don't know what the contract could be so I left it unmentioned...

Comment: @JonStory - You might be 100% right. Even so, it's worth considering because the world is sometimes very small and you never know where you (or someone you're dealing with) is going to end up.

Comment: I don't disagree that offering as much notice as possible, not the minimum required, is a positive thing when leaving a job amicably (I've done so at two previous jobs) - but I wouldn't delay a new job and risk jeopardising the new (more relevant) relationship in order to soften the blow to the older (less relevant) relationship. I'd say give as much notice as possible without delaying the start at Company B

Comment: @Sidius Would telling them the truth be the best option? I mean, yes it does show that you're honest, but I'm not quite sure if that might be a good approach.

Comment: @dwnenr This is what I would do. It might not sound good but with the truth you come out clean and there is no room for false interpretations plus you show that you are professional about it. Imagine if the roles were opposite. What would they do? They would come and say that they found another candidate who fulfills better your position and that you would have to go.
Don't worry about it. You are very new and it won't have any negative impact :)

Answer (score 0):

First, submit your resignation and let your company know what the other company is offering both in terms of work, position and salary(and/or perks).

> Why should you do this?

Cause your company might make you a counter offer, which might interest you. Else, you have nothing to lose. You would leave gracefully.

And before you do all this(submitting resignation), make sure you have already negotiated the salary, position and work details with the other companies, and also inform them about the length of your notice period.

Comment: Would anything change if I do not care what offer my current company might give?

Comment: In that case, you just submit your resignation and leave that place ASAP (after serving your notice period)