# Taking a new job with the knowledge that I may have to quit soon after...Will I burn bridges?

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, new-job, burning-bridges

I'm working on getting a new job. However, there's a possibility that I might be leaving the country in 7 months to get my masters degree so if I were to start the new job, at say the beginning of April, I would only have been there for a little more than half a year. I feel guilty doing this but at the same time nothing is set in stone and I would hate to pass up a great job opportunity just because I'm banking on a chance to go abroad they may or may not come to be (the chances are great but again anything can happen).

Options I've thought of:

Stay with my current job until I know for sure whether or not I'll be leaving the country.

Being upfront about my situation during the interview process. Ergo letting them know that upon hiring me there is a chance I'll have to quit soon after.

Asking potential employers if I an work remotely either full-time or part-time if I find out that I will be leaving.

Am I complicating the situation more than it needs to be and should I wait until I know more or will I risk burning bridges?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: What bridges are you talking about?

Comment: Well say I go abroad and come back to the states in 2-3 years and want to start a career there. They might deny me on account of how they invested so much resources into training me only for me to leave in half a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you have 2 options, stay with your current job or take the new job.  The decision about school is down the road and shouldn't factor into this decision.

Maybe when you get to the new job they will be supportive of your education, maybe you can work part-time remotely (depending on the work of course), maybe they will even pay for part of the school with education assistance.

The other option is that maybe the new job is so good you make different plans for school such as staying closer or doing it part time around your work schedule.

There are many, many different paths that can get to the same goal.  Don't forgo a great opportunity based on what *might* happen in the future.

Comment: Either will be a roll of the dice. The school might happen, or might not. You might do well in the company or fail spectacularly in your first 30 days due to a personality conflict or spilling hot coffee in the bosses' lap. Never bank on what MIGHT be, bank on what you have in hand and be flexible enough to change if something changes (which is almost 99% sure to happen, good or ill)

Answer (score 3):

Might. May. Chances...

You don't know anything about the future at this point, so don't ruin your prospects of employment at this point by looking 6 months down the road at an opportunity that might never pan out.

Stay at your current job, or leave, depending on the opportunities right now. That's your decision.