# Applying for a job knowing that you will leave after 6 months?

Tags: new-job, resignation

I'm resigning from my current job because of a few ethical issues that happened during the past couple of months. This decision is already made. In aproximately 6 months (in October) I will leave my country to do a post-graduate degree abroad. Between this month and October there are 6 months that I'd like to spend doing what I do best - coding in order to raise more money.

Recently I saw this open position at a different company which I fit perfectly. The company has a good reputation, and it is using technologies that I'm already accustomed to.

However, I'm hesitant to apply because I know that I'll be out of the company in 6 months. Should one still go through the interview process and try to negotiate a finite, 6 month contract? Or should one just do a freelance/contract work (which is often hard to find in my country) to fill this time gap (which won't look good on my resume if left empty).

Comment: You probably know better than us whether or not you'd be able to find contract work, and we wouldn't be able to tell you whether the company would be interested in a 6-month contract (but it shouldn't hurt to ask ... early, if your plan is to not take an offer otherwise). We also wouldn't really be able to tell you whether a 6-month gap or a 6-month job would look better to an employer (probably the job, because 6 months isn't short, but it would also depend on a lot of factors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on many factors:

What country?
How long of a contract is advertised? (Do they advertise it for 12 months? If so, they are likely acceptable to 6.)
Will they offer you a contract, or employment at will?  (Legally, in the US, most jobs are at will, thus there is no legal issue of leaving without notice in 6 months.)
How long is your schooling; will you want to work there during breaks? (Maybe they will let you come and go.)
Do you care if you "burn a bridge" with the employer?

Note:  there are a plethora of questions in this group that ask this type of question with an even shorter duration. 
For example:
[Taking a new job with the knowledge that I may have to quit soon after...Will I burn bridges?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87510/taking-a-new-job-with-the-knowledge-that-i-may-have-to-quit-soon-after-will-i?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you let them know your time limitation there is no reason to not try to negotiate a shorter contract.

But definitely do not keep from them your plans to leave after 6 months. Knowing that an employee is around for a short period will change the tasks assigned to the employee. Tasks that require a lot of learning of existing systems would definitely not be given to someone only around for a short time. In contrast welll defined, self contained protects would work well with short-term employees.