# How to get an early resignation during probation period?

Tags: new-job, resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I joined a company before a month and I am finding it difficult to adjust here, I have another offer which expires in another week. The notice period is one month in probation period but I want to quit within next week, how could I convince my manager for this without being harsh or rude?

I already gave indication to my senior manager regarding my interest and he told me to talk to my immediate manager.

**Update:**

I am attaching the mail which I am writing to my immediate manager before face to face discussion.

> Hi XYZ,
>
> I wanted to discuss something important to you since last week, I had
>   a meeting with ABC too but he told me to discuss it with you.
>
> I really like the work environment here but don't know there is
>   something missing and for some reason I feel that this is not the
>   right place for me. I don't think I fit here completely and could give
>   me 100%.
>
> The issue is that there is another opportunity which I feel aligns
>   with my career objectives. I am really in confused state right now, we
>   can discuss it tomorrow if you want.
>
> Thanks,

Comment: "probation" and "one month notice" don't usually go in the same sentence... the idea of probation is that you can leave at any time. Are you sure you have a notice period during your probation? Also, where do you live?

Comment: @Erik its written in my contract, I have joined in UK.

Comment: Related - [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: @Dukeling its not because I am on probation.

Comment: If you need to give notice either way, you being on probation seems irrelevant. Whether you need to give notice while on probation, or how much notice you need to give, is something only your contract or employer can tell you.

Comment: What's the consequence of not giving a month?

Comment: @Dukeling are you joking? being on probation means less responsibility and both employee and employer know that they are testing each other so there may be a chance of resign.

Comment: @vivek: you need to talk to HR. Probation period means that any of the parties can terminate with no questions asked. Period.

Answer (score 4):

From your comments I can see the 1 month notice is a part of the contract so you should definitely give them 1 month.

I would tell the other company that you accept their offer and tell them you are contractually bound for at least 1 more month. When they confirm that you can start in a month, tell your current company that you will be leaving in a month.

Maybe they will walk you out that day or send you on your way early because you are new and there is no point in them paying you more.

If that happens just call the other company and tell them you were able to get out of the contractual obligations and you can start immediately. If you don't get let go earlier than your 1 month, at least you will have given the other company a heads up and you will have a position ready for you at that time.

Comment: If the employee has a 1-month notice period, it's very unlikely that the company can fire them with a shorter period. So even if the OP gets sent home, they'll probably get another month of pay.

Comment: That would be OPs best scenario here. Double dipping in a new company and a company no longer being worked for. But since it is also a probationary period I really don't know how that specific company would work.

Comment: @Collatrl the other company cannot wait for another month because they booked an appointment for me in the embassy. Although I have no such responsibilities can I ask my manager that I can work extra hours including weekend?

Comment: @vivek any way to just attend the meeting and not start official duties at new job until old job is done? There is an alternative here where you give company A your 1 month and then just stop showing up while working for company B. Any way company A can give you unpaid time off or you can use vacation or sick days to make up the difference?

Comment: Both are in different countries so no.

Comment: The different countries has no impact on having company A "let you off the hook". What does your contract say the consequences are for not giving a month?

Comment: @Collatrl I was answering regarding your comment on "any way to just attend the meeting and not start official duties at new job until old job is done?"

Comment: @Collatrl I tried to read the contract but I couldn't find any reference of it.

Comment: You should have an HR rep. Call them and ask what, if any, penalties there are. Doing this will send up their red flags though (which is fine because the worst thing they could do is fire you but you are leaving anyways). Basically, it sounds like you are leaving for sure. You just want to do it on good terms. I think 'good terms' in this case will just be 'best terms possible' so you should just accept that. Don't be rude but be civil and assertive so you don't miss the opportunity you want to take because of this company.

Comment: @Erik it's very unlikely any company will give paid gardening leave to someone on probation. Instead, they will most likely negotiate the notice period with the employee (pretty sure there will be a clause in the contract to allow notice to be shortened by mutual agreement) - they won't want to pay a non-productive person any more than they have to. The OP should still prepare for a whole month's notice period b seeing enforced, though

Comment: @HorusKol pretty much any situation is open for negotiation, sure. I meant more that OP needn't be afraid that they give their one month and get fired on the spot and suddenly be stuck with a month of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your immediate manager. Make it clear that you are not happy where you currently are, and will miss an important opportunity if they do not let you off your duties early. Offer to support them in a clean exit and hand-over and maybe be available for some follow-up questions after your exit if the agree to let you off the hook.

No sensible manager will force you to work, as the potential for behavior harmful to the company is enormous in such situations.

So a mutual agreement which lets you part on good faith is quite common in these kind of situations.

If they really insist you fulfill the contract, you could ask you new employer for support. It is not unheard of, that a new employer "buys you out" of an existing contact.

Comment: They don't know I am working there.

Comment: @vivek Why not? A job requiring notice is something a prospective employer generally should know about.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan its a complex story, I  got two offers in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Give them your leaving date and then leave. Pragmatically they would rather see you leave quietly then be disruptive or bad for morale by forcing you to stay.

Comment: How to do it without being rude?

Comment: @vivek you can't really as you are breaking the contract