# The other offer

Tags: job-offer

Recently, I interviewed two companies, say Company A and Company B. Company B offered me a good position/package which I accepted right away. I didn't bother to reach out to Company A because the interview hadn't gone so well and I wasn't expecting any offer.

Just last week, the Company A unexpectedly extended me a verbal offer, which I'd like to accept because:

1. Company A is my dream company
2. Package is very attractive.

Here are my options at this time:

**Option 1** 
My starting date at Company B is Jan 2, 2018. I could just tell them that I got a dream job and I can't join. But then I'd be sitting job-less for another 3 to 4 weeks, until the other offer is materialized. Worst case scenario: what if Company A rescinds the offer for any reason?

**Option 2** 
Join Company B and resign once the other offer (from Company A) is finalized. This sounds morally wrong to me, because I'd be just settling down during that time.

**Option 3** 
My kids suggested me to extend the start date at Company B, and drive Uber meanwhile. The problems with this option are:

1. I never experienced Uber driving and I am not very excited
2. Company B would definitely say f**k off if I tried to extend my start date now

Please advise!

Comment: @gnat it's probably not exactly duplicate because I have accepted the offer. My dilemma is that whether I should start my new job or renege the commitment, which could potentially be a huge problem if other offer didn't materialize.

Comment: We can't really make this decision for you - you'll need to weigh up how important your morality, not burning bridges and not risking being left without either job is to you.

Comment: Related: [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149)

Comment: I worked very hard to get a job at Company A. I can’t let go A

Answer (score 2):

Company A:

- You don't have a written offer from company A. Say to them you are interested in the offer, and would like a written one.
- **Act like you don't have any offer at all (regarding Company B)** before receiving the written version.

Company B:

- As soon as you receive a written offer from Company A, and supposing there are no conditions to it, such as a background check, tell Company B about it.
- There are two options: they will let you go or they will counter-offer. Be prepared for a counter-offer.
- Do not regret leaving Company B. They would do the same thing to you if you became less interesting to them during your work there.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your sincere suggestion. I will start at B and will try my best to be useful in this short period of time.