# Job change after 6 months

Tags: job-change

I have been at a startup for 6 months. It is a toxic work environment. I am planning to switch jobs. I have not switched jobs so early. I had been at my previous company for 4 years. Will there be a problem in switching jobs?

Comment: Related: [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149)

Answer (score 0):

In general there should be no problem as long as you do not change jobs very often and you can explain why you changed after a few months.

I have similar experiences: Stayed at one job for several years, felt it was time for new challanges and found myself at a job that did not fit the description and where literally **not one single** employee was comfortable working at.

Of course the question came up in my interview. In my experience a very good answer is:

> The work environment at my current employer feels toxic to me and a lot of my colleagues expressed similar oppinions or have already left the company. I really wish to find a workplace where I feel comfortable enough to stay for at least the next few years.

That way you explain the reason for changing after such a short time and at the same time commit yourself to your possible next employer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see an issue as long as you provide a good answer when you are asked and it’s likely you will be.

If asked be honest to the interviewer about why and that should be fine. You also have the proof on your CV that you can remain a loyal employee.

If you are not happy in your work environment there is nothing wrong with changing it. If employers don’t respect that then perhaps it’s not the place to work.

Having been through similar experiences in the past and having roles really affect my mental health I would never stay somewhere for time on my CV if I’m not happy.