# Should I leave the job for which I am not competent?

Tags: salary, quitting, skills

As I said in the title I got the job but I know I am not competent for this job because I do not have enough knowledge about this job. I feel like I stole the job from someone who is eligible for the job.

But I really need money, because I have six family members and I am the only one who earns money. My salary is the only income of my house.

Please tell me what I can do in this situation. I feel I really stole the job from someone else.

I am really confused and upsets me so please tell me what I can do.

Comment: because i passed the interview but i guess that is my luck to pass the interview

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about the kinds of things you feel your job needs you to know, but that you do not know?

Comment: Did you lie during your interview? If you didn't, then it's pretty hard to say that you defrauded anyone. If the company feels you are able to do the job, then you probably are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I quit because I'm not up to the job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/should-i-quit-because-im-not-up-to-the-job)

Comment: What are the consequences of doing poorly at your job? Does someone die or get seriously maimed? Or does some rich person make less money than they otherwise would?

Answer (score 20):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome

> Impostor syndrome (also known as impostor phenomenon, impostorism,
>   fraud syndrome or the impostor experience) is a psychological pattern
>   in which an individual doubts their accomplishments and has a
>   persistent internalized fear of being exposed as a "fraud".[1] Despite
>   external evidence of their competence, those experiencing this
>   phenomenon remain convinced that they are frauds, and do not deserve
>   all they have achieved. Individuals with impostorism incorrectly
>   attribute their success to luck, or as a result of deceiving others
>   into thinking they are more intelligent than they perceive themselves
>   to be.[2] While early research focused on the prevalence among
>   high-achieving women, impostor syndrome has been recognized to affect
>   both men and women equally.[1][3] Impostor phenomenon is not a mental
>   disorder, yet there is research describing various management styles
>   for this internal experience.

If they gave you the job they think you're good enough. Time to believe them over your lying brain.

Comment: +1 Like I used to say to my direct reports "I wouldn't have hired you if I didn't think you could do the job." There is always an onboarding period for every job, but don't be afraid to ask questions!

Answer (score 4):

Do your best to study and learn the skills and duties required for the job.  You will improve your performance and gain confidence in what you do.  Don't be afraid to ask questions and learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say that if you've received the offer, you're likely qualified enough for the job. Impostor syndrome is a powerful thing. It's totally natural.

However, when you say this:

> The thing which confuses me is that I defrauded someone who is eligible for the job where I stand and.....

It makes me feel as if you've blatantly lied on your skill set in order to get the job. Maybe you can provide more context?

If you've lied on your resume and are truly not qualified for the job, it's probably best to identify the areas in which you are lacking. Are these things that you can learn on the job *quickly* and *with no serious repercussions*? If so, get to work. If not, then it's best to probably come clean and apply for other jobs before this gets ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a family of six and you are the only one to earn money. Who are your loyalties with: Are you loyal to your family and put food on the table, or are you loyal to some stranger who would laugh about you if you gave up your job to them?

You didn't steal someone's job. Nobody has the right to a particular job. You went to a job interview, you did well, you convinced the company to hire you, you do your work, and you get paid. It's between you and the company, not between you and some random stranger.

Here's what you do: Next morning before you go to work, you stand in front of mirror and say: "I deserve this job. I can do this job. I work hard, and I deserve what I get paid, and I deserve to be the one doing the job and getting paid. If there are things I don't know, I'll learn them and deserve my job even more." You say this loud. Act that way every day. And eventually, you will believe it. Your colleagues may believe it before you do. Your boss believes it now.